# How to redirect user to new page after submitting user register form?

Tags: forms, users, redirection

I've being trying to write custom module that redirects user from user register page after submit. I read several issues on Drupal Offsite and here on Stackexchange, but could not still resolve the issue.

This is my custom module code:

```
function myregistration_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state){
  unset($_GET['destination']);
  drupal_static_reset('drupal_get_destination');
  $_GET['destination'] = array('query'=>array('q'=>'order_translaton'));
}
```

The URL of the page I want to redirect to is: http://www.sociofobic.ru/drupal/?q=order_translaton.

After registering user no redirect occurs. Instead I get the NOTICE:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in url_is_external() (line 2312 of
>   /home/bnqpdcme/public_html/drupal/includes/common.inc). Notice: Array
>   to string conversion in drupal_parse_url() (line 589 of
>   /home/bnqpdcme/public_html/drupal/includes/common.inc). and  Page not
>   found: The requested page "/drupal/?q=Array" could not be found.

Please tell me what I do wrong, because the syntax for URL redirection I use is the same as explained in [`drupal_redirect_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax that you use is not the same as in the API docs. The `q`is to much.

Also, you shouldn't manipulate `$_GET`, that's not at all reliable. The correct way to achieve what you want, is to add a custom form submit handler and when that is called to set `$form_state['redirect']`.

Have a look at the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542975/drupal-7-redirect-to-a-specific-page-a-tab-after-form-submit

Comment: Thanks, it helped! I am new to Drupal. I though that q is key and 'order_translaton' is value. I just wrote $form_state['redirect']= 'order_translaton'; and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting form after user save is easy

add a `hook_form_alter()`

```
$form['#submit'][1] = 'callback_redirect_to_custom_url_you_want';

function callback_redirect_to_custom_url_you_want(&$form, &$form_state){
    //get the custom field you want to redirect (sample code given below)
    $_GET['destination'] = array('query'=>array('q'=>'order_translaton'));
    $clean = $_GET['destination'] ;
    // or create a custom url you want to redirect 
            $custom_url = $form_state['values']['field_name']['und'][0]['value'];
            $path = isset($custom_url) && !empty($custom_url) ? $custom_url : "";
            $clean = strtolower(trim($path, '-'));
            $form_state['redirect'] = $clean;
        }
```